# Array and struct initialize in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I would like to initilize some elements of an struct and array in C++.

In C you can do:

```
unsigned char array[30] = {[1] = 4, [20] = 4};
struct mystruct 
{ int i;
  int j;
}
struct mystruct e = {.j = 2};
```

But I cannot do it in C++. Is there any way to implement this kind of designated initializers?

Comment: This is C99, not C in general...

Comment: @Oli: Though that was 11 years ago. Would be nice to not have to specify... :/

Comment: @GMan: It may be 11 years ago, but there are still plenty of platforms that don't really support C99 (embedded springs to mind).  If someone says "C" to me, I assume they mean the common denominator of all dialects.  YMMV...

Answer (score 1):

In `C++` struct has constructors (just like `class`), so you could always init your var in them.

Comment: It is a struct that comes from a C lib I cannot compile :( But I was thinking on that

Answer (score 0):

Its always good to Initialize ALL the element in array or structure to avoid many errors.

Below may help you.

**Initialization for struct**

```
struct myStruct

{

   int i;

   int j;

   myStruct()
   {
       j=10; //default Constructor     
   }

};
```

**Initialization for Array:**

```
unsigned char array[5];

array[0]='A';

array[2]='C';
```